# How to paste colnames into col value

Tags: r, purrr

I have a df that looks like below and I would like to modify it to something that looks like the one on the right. How should I do that?
I tried to use `map` but in the wrong way for sure. Could anyone guide me on this?

[image]

```
df <- structure(list(`Student Enrollment` = 750, `Faculty Number` = 21, 
    Graduated = 65), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>%
  map(.,~paste0(colnames(.), "(N=", ., ")"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `across` with `mutate` to modify multiple columns at once; to refer to the current column, use `cur_column`:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ paste0(cur_column(), " (N=", .x, ")")))
```

or with `purrr::imap_dfr`:

```r
df %>% 
  imap_dfr(~ paste0(.y, " (N=", .x, ")"))
```

output

```r
  `Student Enrollment`       `Faculty Number`      Graduated       
1 Student Enrollment (N=750) Faculty Number (N=21) Graduated (N=65)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use `map` method? Just also want to know how to use `map` in the right way.

Comment: Yes, see edit. But I'm not sure I would advise for that, since map is usually used for lists rather than column in dataframes.

Comment: I see. Totally agree. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Stataq Comment on *"map is usually used for lists rather than columns in dataframes"*. `data.frame` or `tibble` is also a special case of `list`. Try `is.list(df)` and it returns TRUE.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pmap_dfr(df, ~ str_c(names(df), " (", c(...), ")") %>% set_names(names(df)))

#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   `Student Enrollment`     `Faculty Number`    Graduated     
#>   <chr>                    <chr>               <chr>         
#> 1 Student Enrollment (750) Faculty Number (21) Graduated (65)
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
df[] <- lapply(
  seq_len(ncol(df)),
  function(i){
    paste0(
      names(df)[i],
      " (N=",
      df[, i,drop = TRUE],
      ")"
    )
  }
)
```